# gee code as a module whose functrions and variables can be loaded and used in another gee script

Tags: javascript, module, google-earth-engine

I have Various codes stored as separate GEE scripts. I want to develop another application that would rely heavily on the functions already defined in the existing files. At the moment, one solution would be to copy the contents of each script file and paste it into my new application. The problem with this is that the code would become long and difficult to read. Is there a way to import a script into a new script if these script files are located in the same directory on the GEE servers? like the equivalent of an `import` function in Python or `source()` in R?

I have tried to use define the variables that I want to export using `exports.senors = [list of sensors]` and loaded the file in a new script using `var seonsor_list = require(absolute_path_to_my_script)` but I get the following error: *absolute_path_to_my_script is not a valid path. Paths must be absolute, such as: "users/homeFolder/repo:path/to/file"*

Thank you very much for any help you can accord.